# cannot remove items from cart in vue 3 with pinia

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

so in the console log it is saying it is being removed from the cart but i can still see the items in the cart... how can i remove them from the cart? im using pinia for state management and the cart is in the state. why it is not working for me?

the code:

shop.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="shop">
    Cart Items: <cart-badge :count="cartLength">{{ count }}</cart-badge>
    <h1>shop</h1>
    <div class="products" v-for="item in Products" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}$
      <button @click="storeCounter.addToCart(item)">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { useCounterStore } from "../stores/counter";
import Products from "../db.json";
import CartBadge from "../components/CartBadge.vue";
import { computed } from "vue";

const storeCounter = useCounterStore();

const cartLength = computed(() => {
  return storeCounter.cart.length;
});
</script>
```

store.js(pinia)

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useCounterStore = defineStore("counter", {
  state: () => ({
    cart: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    addToCart(id) {
      this.cart.push(id);
      console.log("test passed!");
    },
    removeFromCart(id) {
      this.cart.splice(id);
      console.log("removed from cart!");
    },
  },
});
```

cart.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="cart">
        <h1>cart</h1>
        <div class="cartitems" v-for="item in storeCounter.cart" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}$
        <button @click="storeCounter.removeFromCart(item.id)">X</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useCounterStore } from '../stores/counter';

const storeCounter = useCounterStore()

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splice uses the index of the item to delete it.

Do this instead;

```js
removeFromCart(id) {
    let cartItemIndex = this.cart.findIndex(x => x.id === id);

    if (cartItemIndex >= 0) {
        this.cart.splice(cartItemIndex, 1);
        console.log("Removed from cart");
    }
}
```

or if you don't want to use splice anymore (and if performance matters);

```js
removeFromCart(id) {
    this.cart = this.cart.filter(x => x.id !== id);
    console.log("Removed from cart");
}
```

Please use more descriptive parameter names. Rename "`id`" to "`item`" in `addToCart`, since you're not just adding the item id, but the entire item. This can be confusing to other developers and make your code unreadable.

```js
addToCart(item) {
    this.cart.push(item)
    console.log('test passed!')
}
```

References: [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: thank you, but it deletes only the last item first no matter which button of which item i clicked on... how to fix this?

Comment: Are the IDs unique?

Comment: yes it goes like 1,2,3 etc etc

Comment: now, when i try to remove item from the cart, i can, but until the first one i've added. (the first one cannot be removed)

Comment: It works. See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pinia-playground-forked-0z2hze?file=/src/store/counter.js)

Comment: well, the findindex answer does not work for me

Comment: You're right. My mistake - see updated code

Comment: now tested the filter answer and also does not work!

Comment: Have you attempted at all to debug your own code? The filter answer does work

Comment: the new findindex still not working...

Comment: Both solutions will appear not to work if your ids are not unique. Make sure they are - otherwise the solution works as intended. You might have issues elsewhere - open another stackoverflow thread for further assistance